# Is it possible to translate Javacard code to NFC?

Tags: nfc, smartcard, javacard, contactless-smartcard

I was wondering if it is possible to code on a NFC whatever we would code with Javacard ? I have a project where a smart card contains a biometric id to be scaned and and we want to do it wirelessly with a NFC. Do you think that is possible ? What are the boundaries of NFC ? Is it possible to do whatever we do with Javacard on NFC ? Sorry I have a lot of questions I'm not very familiar with the topic.

Answer (score 1):

In essence, NFC is a communication channel, while Javacard describes a programming framework (requiring a processor card with a certain processing power). Of course those two can be combined.

*NFC* is also used as term for rather dumb tags, which may provide some hardwired cryptography (as DESFire does) but not much beyond that except data storage space. There is no way, on which such a tag can process even the most basic "hello world" applet, and mastering the same communication technology does not not help much in that respect. Computing a digital signature can be considered as litmus test, what you really have.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I was searching a lot on the internet how to code in NFC and was only finding these "dumb tags" as you say.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible for some Javacard's to be interacted with via NFC.

See https://github.com/OpenJavaCard/openjavacard-ndef as an example.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes - many contactless and dual-interface cards are in fact running JavaCard applications. When you go to the higher protocol layers, the commands (APDUs) exchanged using NFC are basically the sames as using the contact interface.